# Collapsing margin since Chrome 76

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, margin

since Chrome 76 I have an issue with collapsing margins, reduced down to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f78L4nc3/.

Before Chrome 76 and in all other browsers the behaviour does as expected and does not collapse the margin of the inner element:

[image: Correctly rendered]

Unfortunately since Chrome 76 the margin is collapsed:

[image: Incorrectly rendered]

There are several workarounds for this issue:

- setting `padding: 0.1px;` to the parent element
- setting `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element
- setting `display: inline-block;` to the margin element
- ... basically all options that are descibed in https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/ work.

Is this a bug in Chrome or does Chrome actually render this correctly?

Comment: I'm on Chrome 80 and it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its fixed in the upcoming Chrome 79. Thanks for pointing it out Yaakov Ainspan.

Comment: How did you get this information? Could you link a issue tracker? It could be useful for other people